# Error notification does not show

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to display user errors by this Label `lblStatus`:-

```
    if (txtDesc == null || txtDesc.getValue().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        lblStatus.setComponentError(new UserError(app.res_grid_lables.NO_DESCRIPTION));
        return;
    }
```

But nothing is being displayed. Why?
I have initialized `lblStatus` as `""`

Comment: what value does txtDesc have? did you debug your application?

Comment: It was tested before with different error notification design, no worries over there :)

Comment: Make a SSCCE to get more help or to find the misstake. Your code looks fine.

Comment: Just made a simple example and it works as expected. I just didn't notice at first because by [default label widths are 100%](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-label.html) and the error icon was on the right side of the screen. However, at a close inspection with chrome developer tools, I noticed that I did have an error indicator, but the exclamation mark was all the way to the right side of the screen, barely noticeable... See [this image](http://imgur.com/a/MNrLi) to better understand what I mean